# Make wordpress twenty twelve theme responsive menu toggle with animation

Tags: jquery, wordpress, responsive-design, wordpress-theming

Is there a good way to get the `Wordpress` **twenty twelve** theme menu toggle with an animation when in `responsive` `mobile` mode?

Something like..

```
jQuery(".menu-toggle").toggle(function(){
    jQuery(".main-menu-container").fadeIn('slow');
      },function(){
    jQuery(".main-menu-container").fadeOut('slow');
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use fadeToggle, and click function to toggle your menu with fade. Try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.menu-toggle').click(function () {
     $('.main-menu-container').fadeToggle('slow');
  });
});
```

The Twenty twelwe theme may use something to toggle menu with CSS, or jQuery perhaps. If they have conflict each other, try to remove the original toggle.